# How to consider the newline character(\n) as a delimeter in the file input in Java?

Tags: java, delimiter

I have a text(say test.txt) file which has the following content

1

2,3

Basically it can be considered as `"1\n2,3"`. I am writing a simple Java code which reads this input and should give the output as 6(sum of the 3 numbers extracted).

There is some issue as it is not able to ignore the delimeter here. It stops taking the input there itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  File f=new File("./test.txt");
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
  sc.useDelimiter("\n");
  
  String input=sc.next();
  int result=Add(input);
  System.out.println(result);}
```

Here in my Add() function, I have used regex for considering the \n and ",". The code is as follows:

```
public static int Add(String numbers){
  if(numbers.length()==0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if(numbers.length()==1)
  {
    int num=Integer.parseInt(numbers);
    return num;
  }
  // 1,2,3\n4
  String[] nums=numbers.split("\\n|,");
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
      int num1=Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
      sum+=num1;
  } 
  return sum;}
```

However, instead of 6, I am getting the answer as 1. Where am I failing?

Comment: You are only reading the first value from the Scanner.  That value is "1".

Comment: Why use `next()` with a `'\n'` delimiter, when you could instead just use `nextLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n,]+"));
```

You will only need sc.next() to get all of your values (no need to use `numbers.split()` later on your code